# Change charge_full_design value in Arch

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, arch-linux

I recently installed Arch and noticed that `acpi` was reporting the incorrect battery capacity value, here is the output:

```
acpi -i
Battery 0: Charging, 87%, 00:14:12 until charged
Battery 0: design capacity 3197 mAh, last full capacity 3197 mAh = 100%
```

`acpi` reports that my design capacity is 3197 mAh, when my battery's actual capacity is 6189 mAh (according to the specs provided by the datasheet of the battery, and the actual label of the battery, a genuine HP product).

I attempted to change the value of my design capacity at `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity_full_design` but I get permission denied error, even as root.

How can I manually tell Arch my actual battery capacity?